# Converting string to boolean to use boolean display template in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a model that I have little control over.  It has a string property called Pass that contains a "1" to represent a pass, and a "0" to represent a fail.

I also have a display template that replaces boolean properties with a particular image, depending if the boolean value is true or false.

When I try to use `@Html.DisplayFor(c => (c.Pass == "1"))` in my Razor template, I get a

> System.InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with
>   field access, property access, single-dimension array index or single
>   parameter custom indexer expressions.

How can I modify my view so that `c.Pass == "1"` is interpreted as a true value, and make use of the boolean display template that is available to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a boolean variable in the view:

```
@{ var pass = Model.Pass == "1"; }
@Html.DisplayFor(c => pass)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [custom display template](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html).

1) In the model, add a attribute 
e.g.-

```
 [UIHint("PassFail")]
    public decimal Pass { get; set; }
```

2) Create a Display Template PassFail.cshtml
@model string

```
@if (Model == "1")
{
    <text>Pass</text>
}
else
{
    <text>Fail</text>
}
```

3) Now you can directly use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(e => e.Pass)
```